# iOS app: Authentication with server timing out after 20 minutes. Is this normal, and how can I handle it?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, authentication, nsurlsession

### What I'm doing

I'm building an enterprise app with a set of private APIs that have been provided to me. Unfortunately, after 20 minutes of inactivity, I get 401 unauthorized responses from subsequent calls to the server until I logout of the app and login again (or more specifically, until I call the login API with a username and password again).

### What I've tried

- Calling the login API every 10 minutes or so. This seems to work, but it's ugly, and doesn't seem to be that reliable (still getting reports of 401 errors from beta testers).
- For every web request that I make, I can check for a 401, then handle appropriately and remake the same request. It works fine but it's ugly, there's a lot of duplicate code (copy paste for each request handler...), and well just bad style in general.
- Using NSURLSession's session level challenge handler delegate method. This receives a challenge at the initial login API call of type NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust, which I respond to with a credential created from challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust. This challenge is successful and the app proceeds fine. After 20 minutes of inactivity, the next API call made will trigger this delegate method again. I respond in the same way, and the method is only called once, no challenge.previousFailureCount or anything so everything seems to be fine... but the request returns a 401.
- Using NSURLSession's task level challenge handler delegate method. This is called more frequently than the session level delegate, however it produces the same result. Fine at first, but after 20 minutes of inactivity I respond to it in the same way, and a 401 is returned with no warning such as a recalled challenge handler with a previousFailureCount of greater than 0.
- Recalling the login API from either the task or session level challenge handler delegate method. This has several issues: from the session level delegate, I don't have a way to tell whether the challenge is called from the login API itself (in which case we wouldn't want to recall the login API) or from a different API (in which case we would want to). There's also no way to recall the original NSURLRequest that failed. From the task level delegate - it works, because I can suspend the task until reauthentication has happened, and only call the login API when the task's request isn't for the login API. BUT - this gets called too much - e.g. it gets called about 20 times during app startup. This is pretty ugly and inefficient.

### What I'd like to know

- What is normal? Is the server behaviour normal, and am I missing something in how I should be handling this? Or - is the server abnormal, and is there an easy fix I could suggest to the client?
- Is there a clean way to handle this kind of authentication setup in iOS?
- In my situation, what would you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my situation, what would you do?

Fix the damn server, that's what. Or find the person who can fix it and make them fix it. You have a variety of workarounds, but they're all dancing around a problem that could be fixed once and for all. Find out who's responsible for the server and make them fix it.